# Autodesk Forge BIM 360 API - Activating Service Types

Tags: autodesk-forge

We have been using the Forge API to automatically set up projects in BIM 360, but seem unable to find a way to automatically activate a Service (Field, Glue, etc.).

Intuitively, I would have thought that the "service_types" attribute would be the way to do this, but the services are not activating.

1) What does the "service_types" attribute actually do?

2) If possible, how do we activate a project Service using the Forge API (Most specifically Field)?

Thank you kindly,

Answer (score 0):

Re. #1 
Your understanding of service_type is correct.

Re. #2
Could you try below after you create a project?
https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/projects-project_id-users-POST/

e.g., with the body like this: 
{
    "role": "project_admin",
    "service_type": "field",
    "company_id": "77e4444e-5dad-46a2-ad29-555cc00452a0",
    "email": "my.name@autodesk.com"
}

I verified that having service_type in project creation itself does not have effect. And the documentation is a little confusing. But if you use the above method, it works. Note that you need to have Field license with you account.

There is also a tutorial page: 
https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/tutorials/activate-service/

Comment: Okay, great!

Is there a way to use this to copy project settings from a template project?

Comment: I see Post projects has a parameter template_project_id. Could you try it?  https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/projects-POST/