# BIM 360 REST Endpoints problems

Tags: c#, rest, autodesk-forge, forge

we actually started with the BIM360 API at work. We implemented most of the enpoints that are provided by the API @ https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/

At one point I have discovered some issues. 
After succesfully creating a project with the API it needs to be activated. With first response which tells the project was created under an specific ID.
Taking this ID and creating a new Request I get the following response:

***"{\"code\":1001,\"message\":\"You cannot change the status of a project that has no project admin.\"}"***

OK no problem I think and create a new Request to patch the Project with an project admin. But there I get following message:

***{\"code\":1004,\"message\":\"this project doesn't exist.\"}"***

@https://developer.api.autodesk.com/hq/v1/accounts/:account_id/projects/:project_id/users

The things thats make me curious is that the Projects exist as Response from Get Project and is visible in the WEB Interface from Autodesk.

I tried to add an project admin with API again, but took a Project that was created from the Autodesk BIM 360 Webinterface. And it works, because it is activated automatically.

At this point I can't find a solution which it get working...

(Side note we using C#, the actual Autodesk API, RestSharp, Newton Json...)

Maybe someone else got it working?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

There is a tutorial: 
https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/tutorials/activate-service/

Could you try that?

We had a similar question before and verified it works: 
[Autodesk Forge BIM 360 API - Activating Service Types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47837070/autodesk-forge-bim-360-api-activating-service-types/47857342?noredirect=1#comment82834136_47857342)

Comment: Thanks for your answer... the Problem was an Problem within my Account. In my own developer account the "services" where removed and denied. In the Production System Account it works. This might help some else encountering this Problem!