# Import users to BIM 360 project using Forge V2 endpoint

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

I'm experimenting with the automatic setup of projects in BIM 360 Field using the Autodesk Forge API. The code is designed to run on internal systems and currently uses the [two legged authentication method.](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/reference/http/authenticate-POST/) I've managed to get a project setup, I'm now trying to add a project admin using the recommended V2 [import endpoint:](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/projects-project_id-users-import-POST/)

`POST projects/:project_id/users/import`

As I'm using two legged authentication I'm specifying my `x-user-id` in the header. When I run this I receive the following error:

`{fault.name} - The client_id specified does not have access to the api product`

This happens no matter which V2 endpoint I use; even though all services are enabled in the Forge Dev Centre for the app. I've looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47837070/autodesk-forge-bim-360-api-activating-service-types) and Mikako's solution works, but this is by using the V1 endpoint, I'd like to be able to use this endpoint, and other V2 endpoints. What could be going wrong with my V2 implementations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is because your project is Field classic.  Field classic is a pre-Forge era web services. It's not a part of Forge.

You may try Field API: 
https://bim360field.autodesk.com/apidoc/index.html#api/v1/project_users_method_3

The newer version of Field is under preview right now for customers who has Field.

For more info about what is Forge,  what is not, please refer to this post: 
https://fieldofviewblog.wordpress.com/2017/01/17/bim-360-and-forge-overview/

or about Field classic in general: 
https://fieldofviewblog.wordpress.com/forge/

Comment: Hi Mikako, so as I understand the Forge BIM 360 API allows you to do account level stuff, like set up a new field project, activate it etc. I understand that to do project level stuff with Field we need to use the separate, classic API. In what case are the V2 end points usable when working with a Field project created with Forge?

Comment: It's for adding project members to Docs. Docs did not have API for that. Next Gen Field, which is built on top of Docs, will be work with new one.  But not classic one. I will ask to add clarification to the document.

Comment: Perfect thanks Mikako; makes sense. I think that would be an idea to update docs, they do give the impression it would work with the field service.